# Shoot a Bullet in player direction Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to shot a bullet in player direction but the bullet is instatiated but dont leave the initial position, not sure why, heres the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AtackPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public string playerTag = "Player";
    public AnimationClip startAtack;
    public AnimationClip endAtack;
    public float atackInterval = 2f;

    public GameObject enemyBullet;
    public float bulletSpeed = 20f;

    private Animator _anim;
    private Transform _transform;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _anim = GetComponentInParent<Animator>();
        _transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    private IEnumerator Atack(Vector2 playerPosition)
    {
        _anim.Play(startAtack.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startAtack.length); // executa o clipe e ataca
        GameObject thisBullet = Instantiate(enemyBullet, _transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; //instancia o bullet prefab
        thisBullet.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(thisBullet.transform.position, playerPosition, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        _anim.Play(endAtack.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(endAtack.length); // executa o clipe de finalização do ataque
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(atackInterval); // executa o clipe de finalização do ataque
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.tag == playerTag)
        {
            Vector2 playerPos = player.transform.position;
            StartCoroutine(Atack(playerPos));
        }
    }
}
```

The bullet prefab have a rigidbody2d and a circle collider, also sprite renderer and a animator to handle its animation.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe the bullet believes in peace, love, and understanding.

Comment: I want it to kill them all =(

Comment: I think its because you never told it to leave the initial position.

Comment: the initial position is in the line:
thisBullet.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(thisBullet.transform.position, playerPosition, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

Answer (score 0):

```
thisBullet.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(thisBullet.transform.position, playerPosition, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

`t = bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime`
When t = 0 returns a. When t = 1 returns b. When t = 0.5 returns the point midway between a and b.

In your game probably t has a value very close to 0. It means your
bullet's position stays almost the same position. Also you need a
loop in Atack function to make bullet has the same position with
bullet.

```
while (thisBullet.transform.position != playerPosition)
{    
    thisBullet.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(thisBullet.transform.position, playerPosition, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
}
```

You can set while condition here however you want for your game. In this code it move to player's position every 0.1f.

Comment: WaitForSeconds creates a new object to start anew coroutine, use null instead so you save some GC call.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Burak Karasoy 's answer, I would suggest creating another coroutine for updating the bullet movement if you plan to have more than one bullet or not to block ending animation until the bullet reaches the target.

Declare method:

```
private IEnumerator UpdateBullet(Transform bulletTransform, Transform target)
{
    while (Vector3.Distance(bulletTransform.position, target.position) > 0.01f)
    {    
        bulletTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(bulletTransform.position, target.position, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And update the Atack method with this:

```
private IEnumerator Atack(Transform playerTransform)
{
    _anim.Play(startAtack.name);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startAtack.length);
    GameObject thisBullet = Instantiate(enemyBullet, _transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    StartCoroutine(UpdateBullet(thisBullet.transform, playerTransform));
    _anim.Play(endAtack.name);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(endAtack.length);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(atackInterval);
}
```

Note that I replaced playerPosition parameter with a playerTransform parameter in Atack method so that it holds the position reference through bullet's movement.

To finalize, update the OnTriggerEnter2D method with this:

```
if (player.gameObject.tag == playerTag)
{
    Transform playerTransform = player.transform;
    StartCoroutine(Atack(playerTransform ));
}
```